# Android - Can't style ActionBar supporting API 16 to 22

Tags: android, android-actionbar, styling, android-theme, backwards-compatibility

While coding a Spike for an application, I wanted to do a simple `ActionBar` styling that was backwards compatible with 4.1, whilst supporting Material in newer versions. Therefore I'm inheriting from `Theme.AppCompat.Light`.
Using the new Material color conventions I have this `colors.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="primary" type="color">#b56cb5</item>
    <item name="primary_dark" type="color">#663d66</item>
    <item name="accent" type="color">#ffffff</item>
</resources>
```

`values/style.xml` is defined as so:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="CustomActionBar"
    parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/primary</item>
</style>
```

While defining Material items inside the AppTheme, Android Studio conveniently generated `values-21/style.xml` for me:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <!-- action bar item to support older versions -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="CustomActionBar"
    parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/primary</item>
</style>
```

Manifest is also correctly applying my AppTheme:

```
<application
        (...)
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            (...)
        </activity>
</application>
```

This all looks fine and dandy. However this is what I get when I run the app on 5.0.2 (**API 21**):

[image: Not really that purple-ish]

I won't even bother testing in my 4.4.2 device. What am I doing wrong? All tutorials online seem to do what I did.

Comment: Use AppCompat for API levels 7+. This is the whole point of AppCompat.

Comment: Try taking out the `actionBarStyle` line from your values-21 styles file, I don't feel it needs to be there.

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia Tried it, didn't do anything different
Normal ActionBar. MainActivity also extends ActionBarActivity. I don't really have any references to anything ActionBar related in my MainActivity. Just to the drawer and a drawer onItemClick listener

Comment: Anyway I just did this at work last week, but I don't have the code handy.  If this question is still open tomorrow I'll check back =P.

Comment: @JaredBurrows you mean overriding AppCompat when I custom style the ActionBar for earlier APIs? That's not what the example shows in the official documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

"For Android 3.0 and higher only" section. Notice the themes.xml

Comment: @Digriz You must be new to Android development. Yes, you can style your app the "old way" with Holo but Holo is old and has been out for years. Material design is the latest Google design. google.com/design. Google any new tutorial: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

Comment: @Vikram What? In his style he is trying to use the Holo theme. I am saying to only use AppCompat, just like any other Google tutorial provided my Google.

Comment: @JaredBurrows Yes, I am new... and yes, I am using AppCompat as you can see, by refering to the official documentation about supporting older APIs. Overriding a Holo theme to older devices really doesn't seem overstreched considering older devices use Holo... that's what I believe at least

Comment: Read the link I just posted. If you use AppCompat all devices will display Material Design but only some features can be used for Android 5.0+.  Once again, AppCompat v7 supports all devices from API 7 - API22+.

Comment: using android:Theme.Material.Light won't work since I'll require to use the AppCompat.
I'll try to follow @JaredBurrows link, seems to be more up to date and detail than the official Android docs

Comment: Well I finally got what @JaredBurrows meant by not using the AppCompat. I was inheriting from it but using the android: namespace meant I wasn't using it directly. I'll try to redefine the style.xml with AppCompat and see if it works

Comment: And success! Thanks to everyone for your help. Turns out it was just a dumb and poor use of xml. If @JaredBurrows wouldn't mind, he could wrap all up in an answer so I could mark and upvote

Comment: I will add an answer to summarize.

Comment: @JaredBurrows Right. I thought since Digriz is working with API 16 & above, the code above should _at least work_ - even if the correct way, as you've outlined, is to use styles defined in `AppCompat`. I was wrong here. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Final question: Does this mean I'll sacrifice some of the newest Material goodies (like shadow rendering and animation) on devices running Lollipop for older API support?

Comment: @Digriz No, you won't. `AppCompat` wires everything based on the device's API level. So, `Theme.AppCompat.Light` will point to `Theme.Material.Light` on a device running API 21+ (hence my earlier suggestion). On devices running API levels 11 to 20, `Theme.AppCompat.Light` will default to `Theme.Holo.Light` (hence my confusion as to why your code wasn't working already). And from apis 7 to 11, it will be good old `Theme.Light`.

Comment: Alright, thank you all once again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow the latest Material Design guidelines here:

http://www.google.com/design/ and https://developer.android.com/design/material/index.html.

You can use `AppCompatv7` to support all of your devices from API 7  to API 22+.

Google Developer Chris Banes explains how to implement it:

https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/

And the official blog post:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html.